# Why do posts exit the Low Quality Posts review queue when edited?

Tags: support, review, edits, low-quality-posts

When someone clicks on the Edit button in the Low Quality Posts review, the review automatically gets completed. Why is this? Just because the post is edited doesn't mean that after the edit it's OK.

For example, I edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15205910) and the review got completed just because I edited it, although nobody else has reviewed that answer.

Is there a reason to why this is the case?

Comment: Well, obviously it's because you shouldn't click edit if a post is removable, no?

Comment: @M.A.R. If someone thinks it's OK but it isn't and edits, it's automatically removed from the queue. But if someone thinks it's OK and clicks Looks OK, it's not removed from the queue. Just because the person edits doesn't make it less likely for the person to be wrong. I don't see the logic.

Comment: If someone edits, they're trusted to save that post from misery, but if someone thinks the post is OK, the others need to agree so the post would get out of the queue. It also helps prevent robo-reviewing's harm a little bit.

Comment: @DonaldDuck It does, actually.  It's super easy to sit there spamming "looks okay" on every post that comes past, without regard for a posts quality.  People don't sit there editing every post that goes by, regardless of quality.  It's a much better signal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an edit only counted as a single "Looks OK" action and all else was the same then you could end up with a situation where every reviewer is editing and the whole review process ends with every reviewer reviewing a different version of the post; which makes no more sense than ending the review there and then on the first edit.

The alternative is to reset the review from the edit so all existing review actions are cleared and the post enters the queue afresh. That'll get the post more views in review but it'll also keep things in the queue a lot longer, even if there was nothing wrong with the post in the first place.

Since you shouldn't be editing crap in the first place, it's easier to assume an edited post is OK than keep it lingering in the queue. I agree it's not ideal; but the alternatives are IMO no better.

So you should only be editing posts in the Low Quality Posts review queue if you think you can edit it to an acceptable state; if you want to edit the post without kicking it out of review then just hit the "link" to the post and edit from the Q&A page, rather than from the review.